# fastapi & psycopg2 : password authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I am getting this issue on

```
`docker-compose up`
```

This is my configuration files:-

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "uvicorn", "app.main:app","--host","0.0.0.0","--port","8000 " ]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    api:
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app:ro
        command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
        # env_file:
        #     - ./.env
        environment:
            - DATABASE_HOST_NAME=postgres
            - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
            - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
            - DATABASE_USERNAME=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
            - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
            - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY}
            - ALGORITHM=${ALGORITHM}
            - ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES=${ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES}
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
        volumes:
            - postgres-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

        
volumes:
    postgres-db:
```

When i ran docker-compose build and docker-compose up -d these two commands ran succesfully but when i hit the login endpoint, it's giving the error

> fastapi-api-1       | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "postgres" (192.168.112.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"

My DATABASE_USERNAME is root

Comment: Seems issue with the password, what did you see when run `docker-compose logs postgres`

Comment: fastapi-postgres-1  | 2022-12-30 08:14:47.241 UTC [34] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
fastapi-postgres-1  | 2022-12-30 08:14:47.241 UTC [34] DETAIL:  Role "root" does not exist.
fastapi-postgres-1  |  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"


same username and password were used for local set

@AlwaysSunny

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Don't log in as `root` as that is a system user not a database role as the error message states: *DETAIL: Role "root" does not exist.*. You need to log with a legitimate database role.

Comment: DATABASE_USERNAME is being set to itself.  Where does this come from in the first place?